# Symfony4 и очереди

Tags: очередь, symfony4

Используя Symfony4, как можно реализовать выполнения задач в бэкграунде. Например с помощью RabbitMQ или как для этой задачи можно использовать Reddis? Есть задача, которая должна выполняться в бэкграунде, формирование fullname с fisrtname and last name. Что для этого лучше использовать? Какие есть подходы ?